# LINQ to Entities results inconsistent with SQL query results (with ODP.net)

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, odp.net

My LINQ query is returning some strange results.

LINQ Query (returns incorrect results):

```
IEnumerable<PART_EVENTS> parts = db.PART_EVENTS
    .Where(p => p.OP == op.NCM_DB_NAME && p.Timestamp > tempBegin && p.Timestamp <= tempEnd)                
    .OrderBy(p => p.PART_ID_NUM)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Timestamp)
    .ToList();
```

The results returned in the Visual Studio debugger show the same Timestamp for each unique Part ID, but a direct query in SQL Developer or the Query window (in Server Explorer) shows different timestamps (indeed, the timestamps for each row should be different.)

SQL Query (returns the correct results):

```
select * 
from PART_EVENTS
where OP = 'OP20B'
    AND "Timestamp" > to_date('11/28/2012 07:00 am', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi am')
    AND "Timestamp" <= to_date('11/28/2012 10:58 am', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi am')
order by part_id_num, "Timestamp"
```

I've tried many things to try to correct this and have been at this for 2 days, but I don't know what I am doing wrong or if there is something wrong with the SQL being generated by EF.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before posting my question, I decided to try one more thing: Change the "Timestamp" alias to PART_TIMESTAMP. Apparently LINQ doesn't like the quoted alias. This fixed the problem.

Comment: I had written up entire question and before submitting the question, I thought I would try one more thing. Since that worked and I had already written the question, I thought I would share my answer. The "Ask a Question" form even has a section for answering your own question, so I didn't think there would be anything wrong with doing that. I thought maybe I would save someone else some trouble later on if they were searching and found my solution. Is there something wrong with what I did?